# Can't recompile old "Block King" solidity contract

Tags: compilation, solidity

I've been trying to compile and analyze the so-called "Block King" contract, which can be found on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3ad14db4e5a658d8d20f8836deabe9d5286f79e1#code). However, I can't find a way to run the compiler which is claimed to have produced the EVM code currently on the blockchain, namely version v0.2.1-2016-02-10-7b5d96c.
I have tried to specify this version in the remix IDE but nothing happends when I try to compile it.
I also haven't found a way to get the corresponding version of `solc`.

Any recent version of `solc` (rightly, it seems) screams warnings and errors at this contract. Is there any hope to be able to compile it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v0.2.1 with a different timestamp can be found on the Github release page:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.2.1

There's no release with the timestamp you mention, so I'd guess it was a nightly build at this commit (that's the `-7b5d96c` suffix from your version string):

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/commit/7b5d96c

So if you want to build with exactly this version just clone the repository, check out this commit and rebuild `solc`, though I'd probably just try changing the version pragma and try 0.2.1 first.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did try to do that, however when I follow the Linux build instructions on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop, I get on the command `~/projets/solidity/build$ cmake ../` the output 
```CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    EthPolicy


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (eth_policy):
  Unknown CMake command "eth_policy".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!```